# Компиляция в Goglang и относительные пути в import

Tags: golang

Структура проекта такая

```
├─bin
├─pkg
├─vendor
└─src
    ├─lib
    └─server
       └─main.go
```

Для сборки пользуемся `gb build server`

Но иногда хочется подебажить в Goglang, а он строит путь автоматически

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -i -o /home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main/bin/server -gcflags "-N -l" home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main/src/server/main.go
```

И тут вариант либо менять в исходниках путь в импорте на относительный

```
import (
    "../lib/util"
)
```

Вместо приемлемого для gb

```
import (
    "lib/util"
)
```

Но тогда работает дебаг и перестает собирать через gb

Либо подозреваю что можно как-то настроить через флаги (благо их можно указывать помимо стандартного `-i`)

Comment: Решение найдено самим автором.

Comment: Если решение найдено самим автором, это не причина для закрытия вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Всё оказалось проще.

**Settings** -> **Go** -> **GOPATH** -> **Project GOPATH**

Как бы нелогично это не звучало. Нужно было вместо

```
/home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main/src
/home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main/vendor
```

Указать

```
/home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main
/home/ninazu/GoglandProjects/main/vendor
```

Почему так и не понял. Ведь исходники лежат в **src**. Но при этом без **vendor** тоже не работает, хотя она тоже вложенная. Скорее просто баг, надеюсь в **release** версии пофиксят

Наблюдается в **1.0 EAP**